# How to change what fields show as columns in the Search display screen

Tags: contacts, search-results, fields, custom

How can I change the fields in the list of all contacts to custom ones, and delete unnecessary ones?

[image: all contacts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to display the search result columns to display custom fields, than you can create a profile to include all the fields to include as column(check the result column checkbox while adding the field in profile). Set the 'Default Contact Search Profile' in search preference setting.(Administer >> Search Preferences >> Search Preference).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it later. And how I can delete such fields as "Address", "Postal" etc. ?

Comment: As Pradeep says, make a Profile. If you don't want Address in it then don't put Address in it. The results will only display the fields you add to the Profile

Comment: Oh, I figured out how the profile works now. Thank you.